# Proving that the point of intersection is the centroid

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle *ABC* let *AF* be the median from *A* to *BC* and let *BM* be a segment such that *M* is on *AC* and let the point in which *AF* and *BM* intersect be called *X*.

If it is given that *BX:XM = 2:1*, how can we prove that *X* is the centroid (center of mass) of the triangle *ABC*?

My textbook gives this information without providing any proof. It seems to be true on an intuitive level, since as we move *M* between *A* and *C*, the ratio *BX:XM* appears to change continuously (approaching infinity as *M* moves closer to *A* and approaching *1* as *M* moves closer to *C*) so there must be a unique position for *M* where the ratio is *2:1*, which we know is the foot of the median from *B*.

I was not able to come up with a clear-cut proof however, hence this question.

Edit: This question can also be extended to include the case where we do not know whether *AF* is a median but it is given that *AF* and *BM* cut each other in the ratio *2:1* meaning *AX:XF = BX:XM = 2:1*. This one seems more difficult to justify intuitively.

Comment: My guess is that the textbook might be assuming some previous knowledge. Perhaps try to prove that the three medians meet in a point, and that this point divides each median in the ratio $2:1$ (the result in your book follows from this).

Comment: @ChrisLewis what you are referring to is the basic property of centroids. The theorem I am trying to prove, I believe, is the converse of that: If two segments meet at a point such that they cut each other by the ratio *2:1*, then the point at which they meet is the centroid.

Comment: Well, if you know that principle, you should be able to prove the converse (could there be more than one such point?). It's a bit tricky to answer your question because you haven't shown what you've tried so far. My inclination would be to use vectors but I don't know if you're familiar with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Lewis pointed out in a comment, if you know that the medians of a triangle intersect at a point dividing each median in the $1:2$ ratio, then it suffices to prove that point $X$ in your question is unique. And that is quite a simple task, even in the more difficult case.

Consider in fact a cevian $AF$ and a point $X$ on it such that $AX:XF=2:1$. Let $P\in AB$ and $Q\in AC$ satisfy $AP:PB=AQ:QC=2:1$, then line $PQ$ is the locus of $X$. Analogously, given a cevian $BM$ and a point $Y$ on it such that $BY:YM=2:1$, then the locus of $Y$ is a line $RS$, where $R\in BA$ and $S\in BC$ satisfy $BR:RA=BS:SC=2:1$.

But lines $PQ$ and $RS$ intersect at a single point, hence there is a unique point dividing cevians $AF$, $BM$ in the ratio $2:1$, as it was to be proved.

Comment: Could you please verify that I've understood your proof correctly? (1) There is exactly one line *PQ* parallel to *BC* such that cevians from A that intersect it are cut in the *2:1* ratio, analogously there a line *RS* parallel to *AC* where cevians that intersect it are cut in *2:1*. (2)  If two cevians are to cut each other in the *2:1* ratio, that can only happen if they intersect in the point in which *PQ* and *RS* intersect, because any other point would fail to satisfy the ratio for at least one cevian. (3) *PQ* and *RS* intersect in a unique point, which finishes the proof.

Comment: @jacob78 Yes, that's exactly my proof.